# Composite bar in series paradox

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, solid-mechanics

[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYX5N.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYX5N.jpg)
 Here is the progress and the problem that I encounter. I can calculate the tensile force but it seems like the force cannot exist in the first place ?

P/s: I am sorry because I can only pose the picture. The reason is that I don't know how to write some signals and draw the graph or make some advanced symbols if I type it. It is so thoughtless of me. I am sorry!

Comment: -1 for extreme laziness of just posting a picture. If you don't care to take the time to write it out neatly (such that it is editable), why do you expect us to spend time on your question? This is insulting.

Comment: It is so thoughtless of me. I post the picture as I cannot know how to write the signals( alpha, fraction,...)or draw the pictures. I am so sorry

Comment: Note that this site has [MathJax enabled](//physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation), which means you can use Latex-like syntax to add in equations for readability.

Comment: You can look at other people's questions (you expect other people to read yours) and if you click the "edit" button you can see *how* they did what they did. Then you can do what they did.

Answer (score 1):

You have to think of this solution as a two-step process.  If the ends of the object were not fixed, the object would be free to expand axially when it is heated up.  So first you calculate how much the object would increase in length if its ends were not fixed.  But then you know that the ends are fixed.  So, in step two, you have to compress the object with a force P to bring it back to its original length in order to satisfy the condition that its ends were fixed.  To get that, the compressive strain under the load P must be exactly equal to the expansion strain that the object experienced when it was heated.  That's where the equations in your note came from.